# PushPlugin: Can't find variable: onNotificationAPN

Tags: cordova, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm building an iOS app with Cordova / Phonegap that uses push notifications.

I'm using the [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) to implement the notifications inside the client app.

I've set up the APNS side of things, and when I send a notification when my app is suspended or closed, the notification is displayed correctly. However when I'm in the app, the plugin is throwing an error:

```
Can't find variable: onNotificationAPN
```

When I look at the Xcode output, I'm seeing that the notification is actually delivered:

```
2014-03-02 23:12:58.746 EASP 2014[5792:60b] Notification received
2014-03-02 23:12:58.747 EASP 2014[5792:60b] Msg: {"alert":"testing...",foreground:"1"}
```

However in app nothing happens and I'm stuck with the onNotificationAPN error.

I've tried everything to debug this, but I'm stuck. Any idea why this is happening?

Here's the code I'm using to set up the notifications:

```
  // SET UP PUSH NOTIFICATIONS
  var pushNotification;
  pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

  if ( device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' ) {
    pushNotification.register(
      successHandler,
      errorHandler, {
        "senderID":"<xxxxx>",
        "ecb":"onNotificationGCM"
      }
    );
  }
  else {
    pushNotification.register(
      tokenHandler,
      errorHandler, {
        "badge":"false",
        "sound":"false",
        "alert":"true",
        "ecb":"onNotificationAPN"
      }
    );
  }

  // result contains any message sent from the plugin call
  function successHandler (result) {
    console.log('result = ' + result);
    navigator.notification.alert(
      result,
      onConfirm,
      'Title of app',
      'Dismiss'
    );
  }

  // result contains any error description text returned from the plugin call
  function errorHandler (error) {
    console.log('error = ' + error);
  }

  function tokenHandler (result) {

    var uuid = device.uuid;
    var platform = device.platform;
    console.log(platform);
    if (platform == 'iOS'){
      var os = 'ios';
    } else {
      var os = 'android';
    }
    hash = result+'<title of app>';
    hash = md5(hash);
    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var url = 'https://<notification server>/?token='+result+'&id='+uuid+'&hash='+hash+'&os='+os;

    xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false );

    xmlHttp.send( null );
    console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
  }

  // iOS
  function onNotificationAPN (event) {
    console.log(event);
    if ( event.alert ) {
      navigator.notification.alert(event.alert);
      //alert(event.alert);
    }

    if ( event.sound ) {
        var snd = new Media(event.sound);
        snd.play();
    }

    if ( event.badge ) {
      pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, errorHandler, event.badge);
    }

  }

  function receivedEvent(id) {
    navigator.notification.alert(
      id,
      onConfirm,
      '<title of app>',
      'Dismiss'
    );
  }

  function onConfirm(buttonIndex,id) {
  }
```

Comment: onNotificationAPN must public to window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to get it to work after some more digging.

This is the code now:

```
  // SET UP PUSH NOTIFICATIONS
  var addCallback = function addCallback(key, callback) {
    if (window.pushCallbacks === undefined) {
        window.pushCallbacks = {}
    }
    window.pushCallbacks[key] = callback;
  };


  var pushNotification;
  pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

  if ( device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' ) {
    pushNotification.register(
      successHandler,
      errorHandler, {
        "senderID":"<xxxxx>",
        "ecb":"onNotificationGCM"
      }
    );
  }
  else {
    pushNotification.register(
      tokenHandler,
      errorHandler, {
        "badge":"true",
        "sound":"true",
        "alert":"true",
        "ecb":"pushCallbacks.onNotificationAPN"
      }
    );
  }

  // result contains any message sent from the plugin call
  function successHandler (result) {
    console.log('result = ' + result);
    navigator.notification.alert(
      result,
      onConfirm,
      '<title of app>',
      'Dismiss'
    );
  }

  // result contains any error description text returned from the plugin call
  function errorHandler (error) {
    console.log('error = ' + error);
  }

  function tokenHandler (result) {

    var uuid = device.uuid;
    var platform = device.platform;
    console.log(platform);
    if (platform == 'iOS'){
      var os = 'ios';
    } else {
      var os = 'android';
    }
    hash = result+'<title of app>';
    hash = md5(hash);
    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var url = '<title of app>/?token='+result+'&id='+uuid+'&hash='+hash+'&os='+os;
    console.log('URL IS: '+url);

    xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false );

    xmlHttp.send( null );
    console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
    addCallback('onNotificationAPN', onNotificationAPN);
    return xmlHttp.responseText;

  }

  // iOS
  function onNotificationAPN (event) {
    if ( event.alert ) {
      navigator.notification.alert(event.alert);
    }

    if ( event.sound ) {
        var snd = new Media(event.sound);
        snd.play();
    }

    if ( event.badge ) {
      pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, errorHandler, event.badge);
    }

  }

  function receivedEvent(id) {
    navigator.notification.alert(
      id,
      onConfirm,
      '<title of app>',
      'Dismiss'
    );
  }

  function onConfirm(buttonIndex,id) {
  }
```

So basically what is added is

```
  var addCallback = function addCallback(key, callback) {
    if (window.pushCallbacks === undefined) {
        window.pushCallbacks = {}
    }
    window.pushCallbacks[key] = callback;
  };
```

at the beginning, and

```
"ecb":"pushCallbacks.onNotificationAPN"
```

when registering the iOS push notification.

Works now.

Comment: Could you please explain why this worked, just for the sake of clarity? This fixed it for me also but I have no idea why.

Comment: Since the callbacks are out of scope when they get used in the cordova wrapper, they need to be published to the window scope to be visible

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and ended up fixing it by explicitly registering onNotificatianAPN function on window:

```
var onNotificationAPN = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    if ( event.alert ) {
      navigator.notification.alert(event.alert);
      //alert(event.alert);
    }

    if ( event.sound ) {
        var snd = new Media(event.sound);
        snd.play();
    }

    if ( event.badge ) {
      pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, errorHandler, event.badge);
    }

  }

if(typeof window.onNotificationAPN === 'undefined'){
    window.onNotificationAPN = onNotificationAPN;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Basically the sample describes the function in the global scope.  I had put mine within a function scope that set up my event listener, so it couldn't be found.

```
(function () {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // registration happened in here, as a string
        pushNotification.register(,, {...  , "ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});

    }

    function onNotificationAPN(e) {
        // handle notification
    }

})();
```

The solution for me was to move the onNotificationAPN() outside the function to make it a global.  It's passed as a string, not as a function pointer / closure.

```
(function () {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // registration happened in here
    }

})();

function onNotificationAPN(e) {
    // handle notification
}
```